# external images needed by nib file

Tags: cocoa, image, macos, bundle, nib

I have this nib file, with a large number of NSImageViews that use a large number of Images in my application bundle.

I'm hoping to change the images displayed though while the application is running.

What I want to do is to externalize these images into an application support folder so that when I want to modify them, I don't have to modify the application bundle. I don't want to like reassign each NSImageView to the application support folder in code, unfortunately, since there's a ton of NSImageViews and alot of code to write if I do it that way. Is there any way to tell the nib file that there is a resources folder that's not inside the application bundle where it can load images from?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the [`setImage:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000246-setImage_) method on `NSImageView` and do it all in code?  Then your images can come from anywhere.  You just have to get them into `NSImage` objects.

Comment: Well, if it's the only option... the only thing is that I have to do that about 120 + times.